# jQuery load as a callback for document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am generating dynamic content and adding them into an iframe with the following snippet.

```
function displayIFrame(content)
{
    window.frames['myFrame'].document.open();
    window.frames['myFrame'].document.write(content);
    window.frames['myFrame'].document.close();

    $('#myFrame').load(function() {
        alert("Iframe loaded successfully");
    });
}
```

HTML has the iframe with both `name` and `id` as `myFrame`.

The alert worked when I call the function `displayIframe` for the first time. But not when I make consecutive calls to `displayIframe`.

Is there any work around to make the alert throw whenever the iframe document is written and loaded.

Comment: `load` event fire after iframe loading. Iframe doesn't load in your function for every call. When you use `write()` for iframe, it content make change and doesn't reload.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad, so is there a way to listen the change where I can place the alert for every change occured

Comment: You can fire load event when you want like `$('#myFrame').load()`. Test it, should work.